# How to show individual values from specific condition of dataframe for each bar using plotly python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have a several dataframes with user's order information like that:

```
A = {
    'user': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    'country': ['UK', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'US'],
    'order': [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]}

B = {
    'user': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    'country': ['US', 'US', 'UK', 'FR', 'UK', 'US'],
    'order': [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]}

A = pd.DataFrame(A)
B = pd.DataFrame(B)
```

|  | user | country | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | UK | 1 |
| 1 | b | US | 2 |
| 2 | c | US | 2 |
| 3 | d | UK | 4 |
| 4 | e | UK | 4 |
| 5 | f | US | 4 |

|  | user | country | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | US | 2 |
| 1 | b | US | 2 |
| 2 | c | UK | 3 |
| 3 | d | FR | 3 |
| 4 | e | UK | 3 |
| 5 | f | US | 3 |

I am trying to plot this data in such a way that I can see number of users vs number of orders. And also show the (unique) countries related to the order group when I navigate to the bar on plot (pass these countries to hovertemplate function?). I can get list of lists with unique countries of each order group (country_list), but I am struggling to pass the correct list of countries separately to each corresponding bar. Like in the highlighted plot (dataframe:B, order group: 3, number of users: 4) I want it to display unique countries: ['US', 'UK', 'FR'] related to that order group . Can anyone help with it?

```
data_dict = {"A" : A, "B": B}

fig = go.Figure()

for i in data_dict:
    tmp = data_dict[i]
    X = tmp["order"].value_counts().keys()
    Y = tmp["order"].value_counts().to_list()
    country_list = [tmp[tmp['order']==k]['country'].unique().tolist() for k in X]
    fig = fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = X,
                               y = Y, 
                               hovertemplate='Users: %s' % (country_list),
                               name = i))
    
fig['layout']['yaxis']['title']='Users Count'
fig.update_xaxes(title='Orders')
fig.update_layout(height=500, width=1000)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{y}', textposition='outside')
```

Like currently it displays the whole list of unique country lists regardless of order group:
[image]

[image]

But I want it to display only the list of countries specific to that order group:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Tolegan - I am not able to understand what is the expected output. What do you want in X-axis, what in Y-axis and if multiple bars and/or colors, which field should it represent. The `amount of users` = number of users? The `order number` = order column? But there are repeats there. Can you please update the question with more details on the ask? Thanks...

Comment: @Redox I've made some clarifications based on your questions, please kindly take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the hover templates as you need, please change the `hovertemplate` line to this...

```
hovertemplate="Users: %{text}", text = country_list,
```

A bit more explanation - the country_list is a list of lists. For hovertemplate, it is expecting a list for each `add_trace`. The code is expected in the format mentioned above. Adding just `(country_list)` was causing the issue. Full updated code and working screenshot below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
A = {
    'user': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    'country': ['UK', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'US'],
    'order': [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]}
B = {
    'user': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    'country': ['US', 'US', 'UK', 'FR', 'UK', 'US'],
    'order': [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]}

A = pd.DataFrame(A)
B = pd.DataFrame(B)
data_dict = {"A" : A, "B": B}

fig = go.Figure()

for i in data_dict:
    tmp = data_dict[i]
    X = tmp["order"].value_counts().keys()
    Y = tmp["order"].value_counts().to_list()
    country_list = [tmp[tmp['order']==k]['country'].unique().tolist() for k in X]
    fig = fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = X, y = Y, 
                               hovertemplate="Users: %{text}", text = country_list,
                               name = i))    
fig['layout']['yaxis']['title']='Users Count'
fig.update_xaxes(title='Orders')
fig.update_layout(height=500, width=1000)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{y}', textposition='outside')
```

**Output screenshots**

[image]